# Nodejs Xml to Json

Tags: node.js, json, xml, converters

I am using fast-xml-parser for coverting xml to json

```
    var parser = require('fast-xml-parser');
    var he = require('he');
    var fs = require("fs");
    var util = require("util");

    var options = {
        attributeNamePrefix : "@",
        attrNodeName: "attr", 
        textNodeName : "#text",
        ignoreAttributes : true,
        ignoreNameSpace : true,
        allowBooleanAttributes : false,
        parseNodeValue : true,
        parseAttributeValue : false,
        trimValues: true,
        cdataTagName: "__cdata", //default is 'false'
        cdataPositionChar: "\\c",
        parseTrueNumberOnly: false,
        arrayMode: false, //"strict"
        attrValueProcessor: (val, attrName) => he.decode(val, {isAttributeValue: true}),
        tagValueProcessor : (val, tagName) => he.decode(val), 
        stopNodes: ["parse-me-as-string"]
    };
    
    var tObj = parser.getTraversalObj(xml,options);
    var jsonObj = (parser.convertToJson(tObj,options));
    var lastJson = util.inspect(jsonObj, false, null, true);
    
    console.log(lastJson);
```

My Output this but I dont want see root and elements how can I fix?

```
{
      root: {
        BIREYSEL: {
          bkBildirimdeBulunanFinansKurulusuSayisi: 2,
          bkEnEskTakibeAlinmaTarihi: '',
          bkExclusionCode: '',
          bkGecikmedekiToplamHesapSayisi: 0,
          bkGeciktirdigiBakiyeToplami: 0,
          bkHesapDokumuBeans: {
            bkHesap: {
              element: [
                {
                  bkAcilisTarihi: 20190716,
                  bkDovizKodu: 'TL',
                  bkEnSonGuncellemeTarihi: 20190915,
                  bkGecikmedekiBakiye: 0,
                  bkHesaptakiKonumu: 1,
                  bkKapanisTarihi: { element: '' },
                  bkKayitReferansNo: '7027461580078B',
                  bkKrediKartiTaksitliBakiye: 263,
                  bkKrediTuru: 23,
                  bkKrediTutariLimiti: 12250,
                  bkKurumRumuzu: 'A',
                  bkLimitKullanimOrani: 0.09,
                  bkOdemePerformansiTarihcesi: 0,
                  bkSiraNo: 1,
                  bkTakibeAlinmaBakiyesi: 0,
                  bkTakipTarihi: '',
                  bkToplamBakiye: 1026,
                  bkToplamGeciktirilmisOdemeSayisi: 0,
                  bkTuketiciKredisiTaksitSayisi: '',
                  bkTuketiciKredisiTaksitTutari: ''
                },
                {
                  bkAcilisTarihi: 20110914,
                  bkDovizKodu: 'TL',
                  bkEnSonGuncellemeTarihi: 20190913,
                  bkGecikmedekiBakiye: 0,
                  bkHesaptakiKonumu: 1,
                  bkKapanisTarihi: { element: '' },
                  bkKayitReferansNo: '5670737591250I',
                  bkKrediKartiTaksitliBakiye: 0,
                  bkKrediTuru: 23,
                  bkKrediTutariLimiti: 3500,
                  bkKurumRumuzu: 'B',
                  bkLimitKullanimOrani: 0,
                  bkOdemePerformansiTarihcesi: 0,
                  bkSiraNo: 2,
                  bkTakibeAlinmaBakiyesi: 0,
                  bkTakipTarihi: '',
                  bkToplamBakiye: 0,
                  bkToplamGeciktirilmisOdemeSayisi: { element: '' },
                  bkTuketiciKredisiTaksitSayisi: '',
                  bkTuketiciKredisiTaksitTutari: ''
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          bkKrediNotu: 1369,
          bkKrediNotuSebepKodu1: 12,
          bkKrediNotuSebepKodu2: 6,
          bkKrediNotuSebepKodu3: 9,
          bkKrediNotuSebepKodu4: 17,
          bkMevcutEnUzunGecikmeSuresi: 0,
          bkSonKrediKullandirimTarihi: 20190716,
          bkSorguNo: 72626513,
          bkTakibiDevamEdenKrediSayisi: 0,
          bkTakipBildirimdeBulunanFinansKurulusuSayisi: 0,
          bkToplamKrediliHesapSayisi: 2,
          bkToplamLimit: 15750,
          bkToplamRisk: 1026,
          bkToplamTakibeAlinmisKrediSayisi: 0,
          bkToplamTakipBakiyesi: 0,
          bkWorstPaymetStatusEver: 0,
          krsSonucu: 0,
          krsVeriBulunduMu: true
        },
        TICARI: {
          krmSonucu: 1,
          krmVeriBulunduMu: false,
          tkBildirimdeBulunanFinansKurulusuSayisi: 0,
          tkEnEskiTakipTarihi: '',
          tkEnGuncelLimitTahsisTarihi: '',
          tkEnYakinTakipTarihi: '',
          tkGecikmedekiHesapSayisi: 0,
          tkGecikmisBakiyeToplami: 0,
          tkGuncelKrediBakiyesiToplami: 0,
          tkIlkKrediKullandirimTarihi: '',
          tkLimitRiskBeans: '',
          tkSonKrediKullandirimTarihi: '',
          tkTakFaktoringBildirimDonemi: '',
          tkTakFaktoringCalistigiBankVeDigerMaliKurulusSayisi: 0,
          tkTakFaktoringFaizReeskontKomisyon: 0,
          tkTakFaktoringFaizTahakkukuKomisyon: 0,
          tkTakFaktoringKrediLimiti: 0,
          tkTakFaktoring_12_24_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTakFaktoring_1_12_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTakFaktoring_24_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTakLeasingBildirimDonemi: '',
          tkTakLeasingCalistigiBankVeDigerMaliKurulusSayisi: 0,
          tkTakLeasingFaizReeskontKomisyon: 0,
          tkTakLeasingFaizTahakkukuKomisyon: 0,
          tkTakLeasingKrediLimiti: 0,
          tkTakLeasing_12_24_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTakLeasing_1_12_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTakLeasing_24_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTakibeAlindigiTarihtekiRiskTutarlariToplami: 0,
          tkTakipHesabiBildirimdeBulunanFinansKurulusuSayisi: 0,
          tkTokFaktoringBildirimDonemi: '',
          tkTokFaktoringCalistigiBankVeDigerMaliKurulusSayisi: 0,
          tkTokFaktoringFaizReeskontKomisyon: 0,
          tkTokFaktoringFaizTahakkukuKomisyon: 0,
          tkTokFaktoringKrediLimiti: 0,
          tkTokFaktoring_12_24_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTokFaktoring_1_12_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTokFaktoring_24_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTokLeasingBildirimDonemi: '',
          tkTokLeasingCalistigiBankVeDigerMaliKurulusSayisi: 0,
          tkTokLeasingFaizReeskontKomisyon: 0,
          tkTokLeasingFaizTahakkukuKomisyon: 0,
          tkTokLeasingKrediLimiti: 0,
          tkTokLeasing_12_24_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTokLeasing_1_12_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkTokLeasing_24_Ay_Vadeli: 0,
          tkToplamDigerLimit: '',
          tkToplamDigerRisk: 0,
          tkToplamGayriNakdiLimit: 0,
          tkToplamGayriNakdiRisk: 0,
          tkToplamLimit: 0,
          tkToplamNakdiLimit: 0,
          tkToplamNakdiRisk: 0,
          tkToplamRisk: 0
        },
        donusDegerleri: { hataKodu: 0, islemSonucu: 0 },
        ersRaporTuru: 'D',
        raporTur: 'FD',
        referansNo: '603A796EB0',
        varlikTuru: 'G'
      }
    }
```

Comment: `root` is ok, but what do you exactly mean by *and elements*? Can you share the expected output of yours?

Comment: Could you list the XML?

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AADAkWZcFA    I want like this without root and element array

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AADAMatEFA this is my input  right now

Comment: Off-the-shelf xml-to-json converters (and the same is true of json-to-xml) very rarely give you exactly what you want, and your choice is to either preprocess the input or post-process the output. Consider writing a custom xml-to-json transformatiion using XSLT 3.0, which gives you complete control.

Comment: @O.Harmankaya can you post the xml and expect json output again?